# How to add multiple sheets in excell and insert data in both the sheets using HTML

Tags: html, excel

How to add multiple sheets in excel and insert data in both the sheets using HTML

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in HTML since it's not a programming language, it's a **markup language**.

You should rather look at VBA, C# or any language that can use the office API.